# Rails - Combobox Collection depend on another Combobox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, combobox

I am looking for a way to change the Combobox Collection (combo_two) depends on the option choose in another combobox (combo_one). Follow bellow the Rails form:

```
<%= form_for(@requisite) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :this_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :this_type, :value => params["type"] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :this_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :this_id, :value => params["id"] %>
  </div>
  <div id="combo_one" class="field">
    <%= f.label :require_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :require_type, ([["Element","Element"],["Research","Research"]]) %>
  </div>
  <div id="combo_two" class="field">
    <%= f.label :require_id %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:require_id, @elements, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :qty %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :qty %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lvl %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :lvl %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope we resolve it with javascript (jquery), but I do not know javascript (jquery)

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you have posible get a value for first combo box using a html onchange event in combo box

```
<%= f.select :require_type, ([["Element","Element"],["Research","Research"]]),:onchange => GetValue(this) %>
```

or

```
<select class="combo_box" onchange="GetValue(this);"></select> 

function GetValue(this){
    var value = this.value;
    //Another code for second combobox
}
```

Comment: I thing it is not work because I need "combo_two" as: `<%= f.collection_select(:require_id, @elements, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>` OR `<%= f.collection_select(:require_id, @Research, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>`. What do you thing?